# How to edit Wordpress theme's gallery template to use custom post types?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, gallery, custom-post-type

I'd be really grateful if you could help with this.. I have a template that displays an image gallery for blog posts but I'd like to create another separate gallery to display the images from a custom post type that I have created called "kits". Which parts of this do I edit?

```
<?php /* Template Name: Top Kits */ ?>


<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="main">

        <?php do_action( 'bp_before_blog_page' ) ?>

        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <h2 class="post-title page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <div class="post-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

                <div class="image-gallery"> 

                    <?php
                    $total = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT count(p.id) FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'posts p LEFT JOIN '.$wpdb->prefix.'postmeta pm ON p.id = pm.post_id WHERE p.post_status = \'publish\' AND post_type = \'post\' AND pm.meta_key = \'_thumbnail_id\'');

                    load_template( TEMPLATEPATH . '/functions/paginate.php' );

                    $pages = new paginate(array(
                        'total'         =>  $total,
                        'nr_per_page'   =>  of_get_option( 'gallery_count', 5 ) + 1
                    ));

                    $thumbs = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT p.ID,p.post_title FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'posts p LEFT JOIN '.$wpdb->prefix.'postmeta pm ON p.id = pm.post_id WHERE p.post_status = \'publish\' AND post_type = \'post\' AND pm.meta_key = \'_thumbnail_id\' ORDER BY p.post_date DESC LIMIT '.$pages->limit());

                    foreach ($thumbs as $thumb) : ?>

                        <div class="one_third">
                            <div class="post-img-medium">
                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($thumb->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $thumb->post_title; ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($thumb->ID, 'post-medium'); ?></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                    <div class="clear"></div>

                    <div id="pagination">
                        <?php echo $pages->nav() ?>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div><!--post-->

        <?php do_action( 'bp_after_blog_page' ) ?>

    </div><!--#main-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, is'it working or not or what is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use query_posts:

```
<?php query_posts(array('post_type' => 'kits', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ))
          if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

More info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts